# Do threads work in Ruby Shoes yet?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Any work going on to get other ruby threads working with Shoes?

Comment: Feature names being as weird as they are I can't tell if this is Spam or Ruby Shoes is an actual feature

Comment: @sambo99, I love how Computer Science guys name things :)

Comment: @JaredPar :) Shoes is an awesome little framework written by the Equivalent Obi-Wan for the Ruby language http://waferbaby.com/setup/2009/02/13/_why

Answer (score 4):

Threads work in ruby shoes, the problem is that they are [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) and you have to be very careful not to take out your UI. Besides you have primitives like "every" that allow you to run bits of code every certain interval.

I think _why was moving shoes to run on 1.9 which will give a much more compelling multi threaded story.